# Length extension attack for file download

Tags: hash, mac

I am trying to understand the length extension attack. I found this [tutorial](http://crashsystems.net/2012/03/06/hash_length_extension_attacks/) where the author performs length extension on a file download URL.

Original URL:

> http://example.com/download?file=report.pdf&mac=563162c9c71a17367d44c165b84b85ab59d036f9

New URL for attack:

> http://example.com/download?file=report.pdf%80%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%A8/../../../../../../../etc/passwd&mac=ee40aa8ec0cfafb7e2ec4de20943b673968857a5

I think I understand the explanation for adding the extra padding i.e. so that the MAC calculation can work. I am having trouble understanding once the MAC is verified by the server, won't the server have to download the following file name:

> report.pdf%80%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%A8/../../../../../../../etc/passwd

My question is that once server calculates the MAC and verifies against the MAC attacker sent using length extension, why would the server consider the file path `report.pdf%80...%A8/../../../../../../../etc/passwd` a valid path when it attempts to download the file for the client ? Isn't this path invalid as there is no directory named `report.pdf%80...%A8` ?

Comment: Length extension attack involves forging a checksum for unknown data with known suffix, what does it have to do with URLs might I ask?

Comment: In this example, server will calculate MAC based on parameters in the URL.

Comment: @DannyNiu I just want to understand that in the example given in the tutorial, once server calculates the MAC and verifies against the MAC attacker sent using length extension, why would the server consider the file path `report.pdf%80...%A8/../../../../../../../etc/passwd` a valid path when it attempts to download the file for the client ?

Comment: Hi Jake. The shown attack is just a standard, run of the mill length extension attack. I don't think there is much to understand *cryptographically speaking* about this example if length extension attacks are understood. Yes, the length encoding must be regenerated in the input for the attack to work. The rest, I'm afraid, is not on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct in the tutorial is a horrifying case of non-secure MAC - it can hardly provide assurance of anything.

> Why would server consider the file path *--omitted--* a valid path,

Why not? It's perfectly valid bytestring, although it ends at the first %00 because it's nul-terminated. A path does not become invalid just because it doesn't name an existing file (attacker might want to create a rogue file on the server), or it contains too many "../"

The tutorial uses the examples to show the importance of input-validation, path-traversal defense, and correct usage of cryptographic primitives. That's the lesson we should learn!